# "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException" greater than and lesser than signs maybe?

Tags: java, mysql, syntax, rmi, mysql-connector

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''1'' at line 1

```
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsupermarket","root","");  

    String signString ="";
    if (type == 1)//greater
    {
        signString  = ">=" ;
        System.out.print("1 selected \n");
    }
    if (type == 2)//lesser
    {
        signString  = "<=" ;
        System.out.print("2 selected \n");
    }
    if (type == 3)//equa;
    {
        signString  = "=" ;
        System.out.print("3 selected \n");
    }

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM total WHERE totals ? ?;";

    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1,signString);
    stmt.setString(2,amount);

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

The statement was to return the data according the condition replaced after the "WHERE" statement. I get that syntax error, but I don't see the problem, help please

When data is received, it saves in a 2D ARRAY than is returned to another class called 'client' whereby the data is to be dispersed to a JTable

*I am utilizing RMI

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that parameter binding using the `?` syntax only works to bind *values* in the SQL statement. It cannot be used for operators such as `>=`, `=`, etc.

You'll need to use string concatenation to build the query string. As pointed out by Ksu in the comments, the semicolon should also be left out.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM total WHERE totals " + signString + " ?";

PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1,amount);
```

You may be aware that using string concatenation to build a SQL query is usually discouraged, because it can lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities. This is one reason that bind parameters are preferred.

In this case, where the `signString` value is completely controlled by the program, with no opportunity for malicious users to inject another value, it is safe to use concatenation here.

It's still advisable to use bind parameters where they are allowed, as in the example above.